# MSI Z97 Mpower Motherboard cannot enter UEFI firmware settings

Tags: boot, graphics-card, motherboard, bios

My MSI Z97 Mpower (MS-7915) motherboard does not display `Del to enter...` the UEFI firmware *(v1.11 - latest)* settings depending on GPU used:

- *(MSI)* **Nvidia GTX960 2047MB:** 
   The MSI boot logo *does* appear and I *can* enter the UEFI firmware settings
- *(ASUStek Computer Inc)* **ATI Radeon RX580 8192MB** or **Intel HD4600:** 
   The MSI boot logo *does not* appear and I *cannot* enter the UEFI firmware settings [image: Screenshot]

How do I fix this issue while using the  RX580 or the integrated GPU?

Comment: What you describe sounds like UEFI is trying to load the Option ROM for the RX580 GPU, and if this is the case, it should eventually timeout and finish loading the UEFI firmware, then hand off to the OS bootloader. How long it takes to timeout varies, but it should within 10min or so, at which point you'll need to enter the UEFI firmware settings and disable the option to boot to the GPU's Option ROM _Also, please make use of sentence/paragraph structures when creating questions/answers_ =]

Comment: One image the text is so blurry it can’t be read, the other is just a blank black screen.

Comment: Is there an OS installed??

Comment: @JW0914 i try to do as u recommend

Comment: @ramhound image on the text is the normal text u see on every time a pc boot like "press del or f2 to enter uefi/setting" like that....the one with image using gtx960 gpu during boot....while the blank screen using rx580 shown that pc boot but not going into post as per image...if not going into post, i cannot press del to enter uefi setting....

Comment: @moab yes windows 10 pro 64bit build 2004

Comment: @Rieys - Edit your question instead of submitting a comment

Comment: @Rieys If it wasn't finishing POST or POST failed, it would let you know, usually via beeps (sometimes via an LED, depending on the motherboard), so if it's not generating the diagnostic beeps/LED flashes, POST is likely completing successfully. How long did you wait to determine it wasn't the Option ROM trying to load? To rule out the RX580 as a bad component, test it in another PC. With the integrated graphics, and only the GTX960 installed, can you enable the integrated GPU and boot?

Comment: @Ramhound Even if an OS wasn't installed, the motherboard would still default boot to the EFI command line, unless that boot option has been manually disabled.